# XPath or Selenium FindElement Selector: Find Checkbox for corresponding Sibling Text

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

We are doing Test Automation. We need to locate elements under `kendo-grid-columnlist`, and given a Text Input (Product Type) in `Span`,  locate its corresponding `Input Checkbox`.

So if Requirements, is click checkbox for "Product Type," find the span ProductType,  and find its corresponding input. How can this be done with Selenium Xpath/ByCSS/FindElement Selector?

Input: "Product Type" under kendo-grid-columnlist

Output: Corresponding element for input checkbox

[image]

```
<kendo-grid-columnlist class="k-column-list-wrapper ng-star-inserted">
   <div class="k-column-list"><label class="k-column-list-item ng-star-inserted"><input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" data-index="0">
      <span class="k-checkbox-label">Account Number</span></label>
      <label class="k-column-list-item ng-star-inserted">
         <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" data-index="1">
         <span class="k-checkbox-label">Product Type</span></label>
      <label class="k-column-list-item ng-star-inserted">
         <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" data-index="2">
         <span class="k-checkbox-label">Alternate ID</span>
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. That includes HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following `xpath`.

```
//span[text()='Product Type']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

**Update**: To use `kendo-grid-columnlist`

```
//kendo-grid-columnlist[.//span[text()='Product Type']]//span[text()='Product Type']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

OR

```
//kendo-grid-columnlist//span[text()='Product Type']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

Comment: @alansmith4785 : Check other option as well.Thanks